# Overview & help with drupal files and folders on Win 7

Tags: 7, database, files, installation

I am a newbie. Please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I'm trying to wrap my brain around what is Drupal and how it works.

I installed Acquia Dev Desktop successfully on my Win 7 computer. I want to make sure that I backup all files and folders, but have discovered that Drupal/Acquia is scattered just about everywhere on my hard drive. I found the following (where "Sam" is my Win 7 username).

- C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop
- C:\Users\Sam\Sites
- C:\Users\Sam.acquia
- C:\Users\Sam.drush

Have I missed any locations? Why is everything not consolidated in one folder? It would make life much easier!

If this is not the proper forum for dumb questions please tell me a better place to post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion is probably resulting from things that differ from the Windows environment compared against the traditional multi-user LAMP environment that Drupal is usually built against.

To explain what those directories are in the order you listed them:

- The DevDesktop application code
- Your sites you're managing with Acquia
- Acquia application configurations
- Drush application configurations

This data is separated mostly to accommodate a multi-user environment. So that...

- All the data for the DevDesktop application is isolated so multiple users can use the app.
- The sites you manage are separate from other users.
- Your Acquia application configurations are separate from other users (e.g. your login info).
- You Drush application configuration is separate from other users (e.g. your site aliases).

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt and cogent replies. This helps my poor brain to understand how Drupal/Dev Desktop works.

Comment: No problem! The world of Drupal can be very obtuse at times, especially newbies. I'm glad to have helped.